# Registering callback for OCI HA (High Availability) events

Tags: oracle, high-availability, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to register an event callback function in order to use OCI's HA capability.

I'm following [Oracle's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14250/oci09adv.htm#CJGDCEFG)

As far as I can tell, in the callback function you're supposed to iterate over the affected server handles by using OCIAttrGet function. However, I see two different approaches:

1. `OCIAttrGet(eventhp, **OCI_HTYPE_EVENT**, (void*)&srvhp, (ub4*)0, OCI_ATTR_HA_SVRFIRST, errhp)`
2. `OCIAttrGet(eventhp, **OCI_HTYPE_SERVER**, (void*)&srvhp, (ub4*)0, 
   OCI_ATTR_HA_SVRFIRST, errhp)`

When should I use each handle type?

Can someone point me to an example of OCI event callback function implementation (one that doesn't come from the document I've mentioned)?

Comment: do you have access to metalink? maybe you will find more advanced OCI examples there.

Comment: Thanks! Found it! It seems that the correct usage is with OCI_HTYPE_EVENT.
[link] (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/clustering/overview/awmrac11g-133673.pdf)